# How to get environment variables from a non-executable script in a docker container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have a Dockerfile:

```
### everything, that was commented out with '#' was tried to no avail
FROM ubuntu
#RUN echo "!#/bin/sh" > do.sh
RUN echo "export A=A" >> do.sh

### please run script do.sh
#SHELL ["/bin/bash" ,"-c", "source /do.sh"]
#RUN source /do.sh
#ENTRYPOINT /do.sh
```

And I build it with a Makefile:

```
all: build run
build:
    echo build|figlet
    docker build -t test .
run:
    echo run|figlet
    docker run -it test
```

I just want to have the environment variable from the script do.sh when I enter the interactive terminal.

This is a recreation of a problem from another context. That is why I do not want to make the script executable.
My original context is: I want to call a script in catkin_ws/devel `. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` from this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage.

Comment: A script does not have an environment. A process has an environment. Of course it makes sense to ask for the enviroment which a process running a certain script, is having at a particular point in its execution. For this to achieve, you could put a `printenv >env.txt` in your script. The _env.txt_  will then contain the environment definitions in effect at the time where the _printenv_ command has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try "--env-file=" option with docker run</strike>

```
RUN echo "export A=A" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

-l option to bash to make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell

```
all: build run
build:
    echo build|figlet
    docker build -t test .
run:
    echo run|figlet
    docker run -it test /bin/bash -l
```

Comment: For that to work `do.sh` needs to exist outside the container. It won't work when it's created in a `RUN` statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).